# How do you save two values in a user field using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint-2013

I've got a requirement where I need to assign a SharePoint task to two users. Code below assigns it to one user but not the second when creating a task.
first user value **_spPageContextInfo.userId** second user value **taskcase.Caseownername**,

```
$scope.createTask = function() {
    var item = $scope.taskDetails;
    var taskcase = $scope.caseDetails;
    var updates = angular.extend({}, {
        Title: item.Title,
        DueDate: item.DueDate ? moment(item.DueDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format() : null,
        Status: item.Status,
        AssignedTo: _spPageContextInfo.userId && taskcase.Caseownername,
        RelatedCase: $routeParams.id
    });

    ModalDialog.showWaitScreen({
        message: 'Creating task for case ' + updates.Title
    }).then(function (waitScreen) {
        return CaseManagementService.createTask({
            updates: updates
        }).then(function (task) {
            $log.info('task created', task);
            $scope.taskDetails = {
                Status: 'Not Started'
            };
            $scope.loadRelatedTasks();
            return ModalDialog.delayClose(waitScreen, 200);
        }, function(e){
            console.error(e);
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need get the userid from the taskcase.Caseownername object, and then pass the data like below.

```
AssignedToId: {'results':[_spPageContextInfo.userId,user2Id]}
```

**Refer to**: [How to update Person field with multiple values using REST API](http://sharepoint.sureshc.com/2016/05/how-to-update-person-field-with-multiple-values-using-rest-api.html)

Answer (score 0):

**_spPageContextInfo.userId** sounds like an integer value and **taskcase.Caseownername** sounds like a string value

Is AssignedTo a string? Then just do:

```
AssignedTo: _spPageContextInfo.userId + taskcase.Caseownername,
```

This will save both values as 1 string

Is it an integer? You can't save two values in 1 property...

Comment: _spPageContextInfo.userId is an interger and taskcase.Caseownername is an object. AssignedTo is an array

Comment: AssignedTo is an array of which type?

Comment: spuser array. It's a SharePoint people picker field

Comment: How to you want to add an integer type to that array? Am I missing something?